# Links stop working after 480px

Tags: html, css

So something in my media query is broken but I don't have any idea what it could be.  In any size/format above 480px, the links work, are clickable and are fine.  The moment it adjusts for 480px or less, the links simply stop activating.

I have no idea what part of my media query breaks links...  any help would be appreciated!!

The links in the navigation work, so I don't think that's it, but the links on the main content page stop working.

CSS for content page:

```
#content {
float:left;
width:auto;
background:transparent;
padding:0 50px 0 0;
margin: 100px 0 0 160px;
}

#content p {
font-size:0.82em;
text-align:justify;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
max-width: 500px;
}

#content a {
color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.9);
}


#social li {
display: inline;
padding: 15px 5px 0 0;
}
```

And the changes made for media queries:

```
#content {
width:auto;
position:absolute;
top: 155px;
background:transparent;
padding:0 15px 0 15px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#content p {
font-size:0.79em;
}
```

I have no idea how it broke!  Help?

Comment: please show media queries with exact order as in your css files!

Comment: JSFiddle would be great.

Comment: What do you mean exact order?  The entire media query set up?

Comment: here is the fiddle, what a great tool:  http://jsfiddle.net/NsqLJ/

Comment: @rivenagares Works for me, something would be overlapping the link in your document

Comment: Did you bring the sides of the screen in so its less than 480px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#navpage` has `min-height: 630px` and `z-index: 3`.  So it's longer than content and sitting on top of it.

You can actually fix it by just overriding the z-index on the media query:

```
#navpage {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width:auto;
  top: 0; 
  z-index: auto /* ADDED */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NsqLJ/1/)**

But you may want to override that min-height too (on the media query) because you get a scrollbar with a lot of space. `min-height: 0;`

Comment: Crap...  now the links in the navigation on top of the page stopped working?

Comment: It's because your header is fixed with a z-index of 3.  It's hard to see what you're trying to achieve exactly, but that's the problem.